# Cannot deserialize the current JSON object to a List

Tags: c#, json, xml, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to deserialize this json:

```
{
  "veiculo": [
    {
      "categoria": "B",
      "placa": "NLI2892"
    },
    {
      "categoria": "A",
      "placa": "OML8712"
    },
    {
      "categoria": "B",
      "placa": "PQU1492"
    },
    {
      "categoria": "B",
      "placa": "JIC1381"
    },
    {
      "categoria": "A",
      "placa": "ONB1093"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my object:

```
public class VehicleGO
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "placa")]
    public string Plate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "categoria")]
    public string Category { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to deserialize:

```
var vehicles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<VehicleGO>>(json);
```

I get the following error:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})
>   into type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[rdscanweb.Models.BaseViewModels.VehicleGO]'
>   because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
>   correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
>   (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
>   .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
>   type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
>   object.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The JSON returns an array instead of object, that is the problem, create another class with the List of VehicleGO class and deserialize the JSON to that new class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This structure should do it.

```
public class VehicleGO
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "placa")]
    public string Plate { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "categoria")]
    public string Category { get; set; }
}

public class Vehicles
{
    public List<Veiculo> veiculo { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: categoria, not categoriz